# modsecurity rule for blocking wordpress / joomla admin login - others

Tags: linux, security, apache-httpd

I have an old rule for ModSecurity 1.x to block admin brute force attacks, and only allow them in the internal network.

When I migrated to 2.x, it stopped working. Also the networking ipmatch rules drive me insane, as they do not allow a /8 and only work for a /16 or greater.

I tried to adapt the rule to modsecurity 2, and I came to this:

```
SecRule REMOTE_HOST "!^10." "chain,id:'1',phase:2,t:none,block,nolog"
SecRule REQUEST_METHOD "@streq POST" "chain"
SecRule REQUEST_FILENAME "@pm /wp-login.php /wp-admin/ /administrator/ /admin/" "chain"
SecRule ARGS:log "@streq admin"
```

However it is not working. Some suggestion from someone more experienced in modsecurity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use `.htaccess`? It should protect you against brute force attacks, and it's easely configurable.

We do use something like this, an `.htaccess` file located into the root of the website, containing the following:

```
## Hardening wp - doublelogin
AuthUserFile /path/to/your/.htpasswd
AuthName "Double Login antibot"
AuthType Basic
<Files "wp-login.php">
  require valid-user
</Files>
```

and an `.htpasswd` file, located anywhere you want on your local drive. You just need to specify the full path to the `.htpasswd` file with the `AuthUserFile` directive. Choose whatever you deem to be a sane location for your password file. Just make sure Apache has read access to it.

The `.htpasswd` contain the credentials. You can configure username and password by running:

```
## if it is the first user use -c param (it create new file / or wipe it if exists)
htpasswd -c /path/to/your/.htpasswd username
## if you want to add more users omit the -c param
```

In addition we also put the following rule into `.htaccess` to deny access to `wp-config.php` (which contains sensitive info eg.: the WordPress security keys and the WP database connection details)

```
<files wp-config.php>
  order deny,allow
  deny from all
  allow from 192.168.1.1/24 #(replace with your IP address)
</files>
```

and the following one, which Block WP `xmlrpc.php` requests which is one of the most common causes for exploits. (read [here](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/wordpress/disable-xml-rpc-requests) for more info)

```
<Files xmlrpc.php>
  order deny,allow
  deny from all
  allow from 192.168.1.1/24 #(replace with your LAN info)
</Files>
```

Sorry I can't directly help with your issue, if the above is not what you are looking for, I hope this link can give you some help : http://artefact.io/brute-force-protection-modsecurity/

Comment: The .htaccess answer is a much better solution for you than trying to set up mod_sec rules. On a typical shared hosting server, there are more than 50 distinct rules and still brutes will hit the login pages.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful answer. We provide services for internal customers, and I am talking about a server with around 300 vhosts, so while for some more problematic sites I can very well use .htaccess, and will follow your recommendations, it is not feasible to automate the process as I might destroy the actual ones. My main problem with modsecurity is the difference of syntax from v1 to v2, used to have a global rule that enforce server-wide rules working well. Will check with more attention your link.